# SBT not finding scalatest for scala 2.10.1

Tags: sbt, scalatest

I'm trying to learn how to use SBT and the following simple example I've found fails to find the version for scalatest:

```
name := "DoingItWrong"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test"
)
```

I was using maven before trying sbt and the following dependency works ok:

```
<dependency>                                                            
   <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>                                    
   <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>                             
   <version>1.9.1</version>                                            
</dependency>
```

I got the following output trying to run SBT:

```
$ sbt package              
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/rafael/.sbt/plugins
[info] Set current project to DoingItWrong (in build file:/home/rafael/Dev/DoingItWrong/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/rafael/Dev/DoingItWrong/}default-c52ace...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10.1;1.9.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10.1;1.9.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/rafael/.ivy2/local/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.10.1/1.9.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Sonatype snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.10.1/1.9.1/scalatest_2.10.1-1.9.1.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.10.1/1.9.1/scalatest_2.10.1-1.9.1.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10.1;1.9.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/home/rafael/Dev/DoingItWrong/}default-c52ace/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10.1;1.9.1: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jun 6, 2013 9:45:49 AM
```

I'm I lacking some repository or something?

I also tried `scalaVersion := "2.10.0"` and `2.10.0-M4`. What is the latest available version for scalatest for Scala 2.10 via SBT?

Comment: That works for me. I've just tried in my application to import it. I use scalaVersion := 2.10.0.  Could you retry now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be sure that it's not a potential SBT project's configuration issue, don't use for now the `%%` notation. Indeed, this one automatically chooses the Jar version corresponding to your current scala version, which may be different than the one you expect (oversight in your conf, conflict of variables in some configuration files etc...).

Prefer this in order to isolate your "error" context:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "1.9.1" % "test"
```

I've just tried it, that works well.

Comment: Hum... it worked with this change. Thanks. I can understand exactly why (my `build.sbt` file only had what I stated above and I had no other sbt files on the project) but it works.

Comment: Are you sure, you've tried with `scalaVersion := "2.10.0"` set instead of `scalaVersion := "2.10.1"`?

Comment: Yep. I tried lots of combinations of scalaVersion and scalatest version tag. The issue seems to be the %% operator. When I use % everything works ok.

Comment: Strange,  according to there: http://www.scalatest.org/download, it sounds the notation `%%` is only usable for 2.10 > your scala version > 2.9. Since you have 2.10, you can't use it. I seek for the reason why...

Comment: i noticed that sbt tries to employ the maven repo's into its resolvers list when a single "%" is used. Otherwise, it just scans through the typesafe repo(s) alone! I run on Scala v2.12 & SBT v0.13.13