# Can't Run `test` in Scala Test with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

**src/main/scala/Testing.scala**

```
package common
object Add1Method {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = 100+2
  }
```

**project/build.sbt**

```
name := "Foo"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "1.9.1" % "test"

resolvers +=  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

resolvers +=  "Sonatype Releases" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
```

**src/test/scala/Test.scala**

```
package test

import common.Testing
import org.scalatest._

class Test extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

      "running main" should "return 102" in {
        val result = Add1Method.main(Array("asdf"))
        assert(result == 102)
      }
    }
```

But, when I run `test` from SBT, the following 4 compile-time errors:

```
[error] Test.scala:4: object scalatest is not a member of package org
[error] import org.scalatest._
[error]            ^
[error] Test.scala:6: not found: type FlatSpec
[error] class Test extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
[error]                        ^
[error] Test.scala:6: not found: type Matchers
[error] class Test extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
[error]                                      ^
[error] Test.scala:8: value should is not a member of String
[error]   "running main" should "return 102" in {
[error]                          ^
[error] four errors found
```

Note that I tried the suggested answer in [SBT not finding scalatest for scala 2.10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962690/sbt-not-finding-scalatest-for-scala-2-10-1) without success.

The ScalaTest example uses the same imports - http://www.scalatest.org/quick_start.

Comment: The example on the site uses "2.0". I am wondering if you reloaded your sbt.

Comment: I updated to `libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"`, but same errors when running `test`.

Comment: If you do `reload` then `clean` and after that `test`, what is the output? You can put the result in a public [gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: @EECOLOR, same 4 compile-time errors as my above question. Note that I ran `reload` and `clean`, and finally `test`. I understand that you were concerned that I failed to run `reload` to update my `build.sbt` settings.

Comment: Kevin, if you post the same question to both Stack Overflow and a mailing list (scalatest-users), both posts should link to the other, so that people don't waste their time answering something in one place that was already answered in another.

Comment: Thanks @SethTissue. I'll definitely do that in the future.  My bad

Comment: This wasn't your problem but it may help someone else in the future: For me I accidentally created the test inside `src/main` instead of `src/test`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `build.sbt` is in the wrong place. It should not be in `project/` but in the root directory, next to the `src` directory.

See [Directories](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Directories.html#sbt-build-definition-files) in the sbt documentation for more info.

Comment: Thanks, @EECOLOR. That did the trick. Sorry I didn't chat with you. I had just signed off from work :)